# In C# what does Type<T> this [int index] means?

Tags: c#, this

I ran into this code today, and I cannot figure out it's meaning. I couldn't find an MSDN post about it

```
public interface ITestCase <out Tview, out Tmodel>
where ... 
where ...
{
  ...
  IUITestCase<Tview> this[int index] {get;}
  ...
}
```

The rest of the code seems useless for the question, but i'll post it if needed. 
 Has anybody an explanation for the property ? Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are `Indexers`. See [MSDN Dcumenation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx)

---

#### Update

*First of all thanks to `Alexandru-Ionut Mihai` for pointing out, that this is a **generic** construct of `Indexers`.*

An indexer provides array-like syntax. It allows a type to be accessed the same way as an array. As seen about in your example Code.

Comment: @ArthurAttout If the Answer is correct to your question, please mark it as so.

Answer (score 1):

These are `indexers` with `generic types`. So, we can say that we have **generic indexers**.

**An indexer allows an object to be indexed such as an array.**

Comment: I think OP is aware of **generics**. Still +1 for further readers.